# define class with variable number of inputs in python

Tags: python, class, constructor

How does one define a class constructor with two possible inputs:

```
class MSMeshFace(object):
    def __init__(self, A=None, B=None, C=None)
    def __init__(self, A=None, B=None, C=None, D=None)
```

So obviously this doesnt work but that's what i would like it to behave as. If someone inputs A,B,C then construct MSMeshFace from those three variables else if someone inputs A,B,C,D then construct it from all four. What's the proper way to do that so that when I call it it looks like this:

```
newFace = MSMeshFace(A, B, C)
```

or

```
newFace = MSMeshFace(A,B,C,D)
```

and they both work properly but first one creates a "triangular" face and second a "quad". I dont want to do something like newFace = MSMeshFace().Quad(A,B,C,D) if possible.

or should i do something like:

```
class MSMeshFace(object):

    def __init__(self, a= None, b= None, c= None, d= None):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
            self.d = d
            if self.d == None:
                    triangleFace = MSMeshFace(self.a, self.b, self.c)
                    return triangleFace
            else:
                    quadFace = MSMeshFace(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
                    return quadFace
    def addData(self, data):
            self.data = data
```

is this a valid way to construct that class?

Comment: well if you are using default parameters, then just do some `if D: do_this()` stuff?, since they have default values, you dont have to include them when you create the object. `newface = MSMeshFace()` would still be valid

Comment: def __init__(self, *args) will take any amount

Comment: @Yoriz care for an example?

Comment: @TehTris so if someone leaves D out when calling it it will still be None but it initiates correctly regardless? It's just that when you call self.D it will return None. Right?

Comment: You've answered your own question anyway. Except I would suggest `if self.D is None:`.

Comment: D will still be None because it is the default and it didn't change by only inputting A B and C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MSMeshFace(object):
    def __init__(self, A, B, C, D=None):
        if D is None:
            # build mesh using (A,B,C)
        else:
            # build mesh using (A,B,C,D)

 triFace = MSMeshFace(A,B,C)
 quadFace = MSMeshFace(A,B,C,D)
```

Comment: `if D:` is always better than `if D is not None`, also this leads to some weird recursion

Comment: Not true @TehTris - `if D:` fails in cases where D is given a falsy value that is still valid input (e.g. `0`); `if D is not None` is correct if that's a possibility.

Comment: you are right, didnt think of that. totally a possibility that a zero would go in there +1 for correcting me.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this code will run into infinite recursion.

Comment: It is an infite loop in any case.

Comment: Oops, overlooked the class names being the same. Fixed.

Comment: @figs does that mean that i need a seperate class for building mesh from ABC and different one for building it from ABCD and then I just create one overacrching class that calls either based on number of inputs? is that the idea?

Comment: it depends on what you are using D for, if D has a default value somewhere else in the code you may be able to do something at the beginning like `if D is None: D = 'wateverdefaultvalue'`, if A B C D and A B C are COMPLETELY different, then you may have to construct two seperate classes that get called depedning on which are there

Comment: That's a separate design decision really. You could just have two methods in your class, say, `build_triangle_mesh` and `build_quad_mesh` and call the relevant one.

Comment: @figs I added what I think is the correct way to construct that class to the question. Will that work? Any improvements that I can make to it? Thank you!

Comment: @konrad that code won't work as it will indefinitely try to call itself. You would have to change the class name of either the main class or the classes you are returning. It sounds like you are trying to build a factory design pattern where the main class decides which class you need, creates it, and returns it. Best to ask a new question about design choices and you can get a better answer :)